# setting user.dir system property in JBoss 5.1

Tags: java, jboss

In JBoss 4.2.3 the System property 'user.dir' is defined to be

```
<JBoss-root>/bin
```

when I ran the same application on JBoss 5.1 I noticed that it cannot find the System property user.dir

why there is no default definition for version 5.1? 
and how can I define it manually? I followed [this](http://www.hugotroche.com/my_weblog/2008/07/setting-java-sy.html) suggestion
and added my property into **properties-service.xml**
but it had no affect and still JBoss couldn't find the system:user.dir value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the solution to my problem](http://www.coderanch.com/t/496619/JBoss/setting-user-dir-system-property). I didn't describe the proeblem correctly in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  Did you notice that the Properties attribute in properties-service.xml is commented out by default?

Comment: It's not commented in my file. How can I view the list of properties that are defined through JBoss console?

Comment: The mbean jboss:name=SystemProperties,type=Service has a method, showAll().  It's accessible in jmx-console.